# PyCharm autocomplete is not displaying the methods and classes

Tags: python, pycharm

I am learning how to create packages in python and as a part of that exercise I set up the `__init__.py` files in the submodules. I have a folder structure that looks like the following

```
├── parent_folder
│   ├── README.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base_estimator.py
│   ├── child_folder_1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── naming_constants.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── value_constants.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── naming_constants.py
│   │   └── value_constants.py
│   ├── child_folder_2
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── base.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── adult.csv
│   │   ├── axis_fi_nan_treated.csv
│   │   ├── bank_additional_full.csv
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── boston_house_prices.csv
│   │   ├── breast_cancer.csv
```

The package is the `parent_folder` and  `child_folder_1`, `child_folder_2` are the sub modules in it

The `__init__.py` file in the `parent_folder` looks like this

```
__all__ = ['child_folder_1', 'child_folder_2', 'base_estimator']
```

The `__init__.py` file inside `child_folder_2` looks like

```
from .base import load_pima_diabetes
from .base import load_titanic
from .base import load_iris
from .base import load_data
from .base import load_breast_cancer_wisconsin
from .base import load_boston_house_prices
from .base import load_axis_fi
from .base import load_bank_subscription
from .base import load_adult_income


__all__ = ['load_iris', 'load_boston_house_prices', 'load_bank_subscription', 'load_adult_income',
           'load_breast_cancer_wisconsin', 'load_pima_diabetes', 'load_axis_fi', 'load_titanic', 'load_data']
```

Where `.base` is a file in `child_folder_2` that defines several functions to load datasets. The `__init__.py` for the `child_folder_1` is blank.

Doing this has created a small issue for me- autocomplete. Since I have made these `__init__.py` files, PyCharm doesn't show anything in autocomplete. I tried importing the `child_folder_2` submodule by typing in `from parent_folder.` but then nothing displays.

Strange thing is that the code runs. It seems like I am missing on something but I can't figure out what. Any ideas on how why this might be occuring?

Comment: Could you please create a ticket in [PyCharms' bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)? I replicated the project, but the completion works ok. Which Python version do you use?

Comment: I am using python 3.6. I am trying to sort out the issue on my end. I think the issue is from my side.